# MS Access 2016 Join on Multiple Fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join, ms-access-2016

I have two tables similar to the following
[query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWuMa.jpg)
and
[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09CLU.jpg)
How do I combine both into a table where it looks like table 1 with another field named as z

I've been trying this in SQL but it doesn't work after the first OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT [table 1].[a], [table 1].[v], [table 1].[w], [table 1].[x], 
[table 1].[y], [query 1].[z]
FROM [detc-or-ar] 
LEFT JOIN [query 1] ON [table 1].[v] = [query 1].v 
OR [query 1].[w] = [query 1].w 
OR [query 1] ON ([table 1].[x] = [query 1].x
OR [query 1] ON ([table 1].[y] = [query 1].y;
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your two tables `query 1` and `table 1`. You current `ON` clause has `OR [query 1].[w] = [query 1].w` which will ALWAYS be true causing a cartesian product of your two tables (joining every record to every record). So... what field(s) are common between the two tables. You can share some sample data from the `query 1` output and the `table 1` and that may help us understand. Right now it's just generic table and field names, so there's not much we can do.

Comment: As a follow up, if I had to guess I would say that your `ORs` should be changed to `AND` and your `[query 1].[w] = [query 1].w` should be changed to `[query 1].[w] = [table 1].w`. The query would then read "Join these two tables where fields v,w,x, and y are common between the two tables, then pull `z` from `query 1`.

Comment: Just got it
Thanks so much! just changed it to
   `LEFT JOIN [query 1] ON [table 1].[v] = [query 1].v 
    OR [table 1].[w] = [query 1].w 
    OR [table 1].[x] = [query 1].x
    OR [table 1].[y] = [query 1].y;`

Didn't notice there were other on clauses

Comment: You are not clear about what your desired output is. Please just give the desired output. Also please do not use images/links when you can use text. Format tables in code blocks.